# Finding in array is not finding anything

Tags: php, arrays

When I upload an file and would like to check if in the file the text `aantal` is present. I am using this code to check:

```
<?php
// Loop through each file
for( $i=0 ; $i < $total ; $i++ )
{
    // Get the temp file path
    $tmpFilePath = $_FILES['upload']['tmp_name'][$i];

    // Make sure we have a file path
    if ($tmpFilePath != "")
    {
        //Setup our new file path
        $newFilePath = $config['temp_uploads'].'/'.$_FILES['upload']['name'][$i];

        // Upload the file into the temp dir
        if(move_uploaded_file($tmpFilePath, $newFilePath))
        {
            //Handle other code here
            echo 'Upload succes<br /><br />';
            echo 'File name: '.$_FILES['upload']['name'][$i];
            echo '<br /><br />';

            $lines = file($newFilePath); //file in to an array

            echo 'Find: '.array_search('Aantal', $lines);
            echo '<br /><br />';

            print_r($lines);
            echo '<br /><br />';

            // remove file
            unlink($newFilePath);
        }
        else
        {
            echo 'Upload error<br /><br />';
        }
    }
}
?>
```

The filehandeling is not giving any errors and the text `Aantal` is present (needle 2224).
The output after uploading is:

```
    Upload succes

    File name: BP 01.dxf

    Find: 

    Array ( [0] => 0 [1] => SECTION [2] => 2 [3] => HEADER [4] => 9 [5] => $ACADVER [6] => 1 [7] => AC1027 [8] => 9 [9] => $ACADMAINTVER [10] =>

..... // skipping these lines because of Stackoverflow limits

=> 1 [2223] => #22 Aantal:2 [2224] => 7 [2225] => BEMATING [2226] =>

    ..... // skipping these lines because of Stackoverflow limits

    => CELLSTYLE_END [12132] => 0 [12133] => ENDSEC [12134] => 0 [12135] => EOF )
```

Any suggestions why the needle or the text of needle 2224 is not shown?

Comment: `"#22 Aantal:2"` is different from `"Aantal"`. `array_search` looks for an exact match, not something that contains what you're looking for.

Comment: Please do `var_dump($lines[2223])`. Check if string does not have some additional characters

Comment: @Justinas it's right there in the output: `[2223] => #22 Aantal:2 `. It's not the same string

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`"#22 Aantal:2"` is different from `"Aantal"`. [`array_search`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-search.php) looks for an exact match, not something that contains what you're looking for.

You would be better served by [`preg_grep`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-grep.php):

```
$matches = preg_grep('/Aantal/', $lines);
foreach ($matches as $m) {
    echo "Find " . $m;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to search loosely like that you can use preg_grep.

```
$match = reg_grep("/Aantal/", $lines);
```

This uses regex and finds any array values containing "Aantal"

Answer (score 0):

even already answered I have given a try

- it reads each line in the file into array
- then explode each line into word using `space` as dilimiter
- then search for first `occurrence` of desired `word` into that `word array`
- **In Image output counter differs because of loop start from zero**
- Not Finding or testing multiple occurrence

  ```
  <?php
     // Loop through each file
     function find_word($word){
     $rows = file('test.txt');

     foreach($rows as $row_no => $row_content){

     $words = explode(' ',$row_content);
     if(array_search($word,$words)){
        echo $row_no ." \t\t\t\t " .$row_content;
        echo '<hr />';
     }else{
        echo 'NOT FOUND<hr />';
      }
    }
   }

   echo find_word('Aantal');
   ?>
  ```

[image]